# Recursive calling in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

I am new to Angulrajs and I want to list a JSON object in html page. I think I have to go into the object recursively. Is there any thing that can be done in Angularjs.

I have nested objects. So, I have to go into that.

Comment: just use recursion as you normally would in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to use [ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to loop over your object. Like this.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="stuff in things"> stuff </li>
</ul>
```

*after your edit. You think you have to use recursion because you have nested objects. That's not entirely true. You could use multiple ng-repeats. Something like this.

```
 <div>
  <div ng-repeat="stuff in things">
    <span> stuff </span>
    <div ng-repeat="morestuff in stuff">
      moreStuff
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `ng-repeat` does not offer recursion, only iteration.

Comment: Yes, which brings up the question of why recursion is needed. I would wager it's not in this case.

Comment: well, you can ask about it in a comment, rather than guessing (even though the OP has specifically stated he would *"have to go into the object recursively"*).

Comment: Let's go ahead and not pick and choose what he said. I believe what he said was 'I THINK I have to go into the object recursively'. That big 'I think' was the reason I posted my answer. Odds are I'm wrong but if I am right ng-repeat is going to save him a ton of time.

Comment: i didn't mean to pick and choose, i was just referring to the perceived intention. either way, the answer was well updated. i withdraw my downvote.

Comment: I can also see where you're coming from. Thanks for the withdraw and have a good night or day :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for true recursion, here's what you could do (for example, recursively nested comments)

```
<div class="panel panel-default" 
ng-repeat="comment in comments" 
ng-include="'comment_recursion.html'">
</div>

<!-- == Recursion script  == -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="comment_recursion.html">
    <div ng-controller="CommentCtrl">   
        <div class="panel-heading">
            {{comment.author}}
            <%= render "layouts/controverse_btns" %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            {{comment.text}}
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <span>Created :{{comment.created_at}}, </span>
            <span>Last Edited : {{comment.updated_at}}</span>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Comment replies (other comments), might want to indent to the right --> 
    <div class="reply" ng-if="comment.replies">
        <div class="panel panel-default" 
            ng-repeat="comment in comment.replies" 
            ng-include="'comment_recursion.html'">
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```