# Is it possible to ng-repeat without nesting?

Tags: angularjs

Data looks like this...

```
[
    {"folderId":1, "media":[
        {"imageId":1},
        {"imageId":2}
    ]},
    {"folderId":2, "media":[
        {"imageId":3}
    ]},
]
```

Is it possible to ng-repeat over the media objects in all the folders without nesting?  Something like ng-repeat="image in media in folders"?

Comment: [this was just asked now](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22396041/547020). i guess we really need **`ng-tree`**...

Comment: You should be able to use the techniques described here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163027/show-an-aggregated-list-in-angularjs